# How to efficiently query deep-linked nodes with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Sorry for being a complete noob regarding graph databases and neo4j. I'm trying to design my first graph database with neo4j, but after reading their [hyperedge example](https://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/cypher-cookbook-hyperedges.html) I'm a bit confused about what to do in my current situation.

[image]

Suppose that in addition to User, Group and Roles you also have Permissions (a role can have n permissions).

I'm interested in returning all permissions for a given user, so I tried to convert that hyperedges example and ended up with something that obviously will never work:

A relationsnip called has_permission_in_role_in_group. Obviously that won't work. since we want to return all permissions for the given user.

If hyperedges is no good here, how would you then efficiently get a users permissions with neo4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a given `Role`'s `Permission`s are independent of `User`s and `Group`s, you wouldn't need a hyperedge involving `Permission`s, and you'd just need a `hasPermission` relationship between a `Role` and each of its `Permission`s.

In this case, to get all the distinct `Permission`s for "User1", you can just use this query:

```
MATCH (u:User {name: 'User1'})-[:hasRoleInGroup]->()-[:hasRole]->()-[:hasPermission]->(p)
RETURN u, COLLECT(DISTINCT p) AS permissions;
```